# PowerShell shell hangs when saving results to variable (Azure Pipelines List)

Tags: json, powershell, variable-assignment, azure-cli

I am trying to save the results of an Azure CLI (`az pipelines list`) command to a variable, but the shell/script hangs.

If I run the command on its own, it works:

```bsh
PS C:\> az pipelines list --project PROJECT_NAME --name PIPELINE_NAME --output json
This command is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
[
  {
    "authoredBy": {
      # ...
    },
    "createdDate": "2019-12-07T00:08:03.620000+00:00",
    "draftOf": null,
    "drafts": [],
    "id": 541,
    "latestBuild": null,
    "latestCompletedBuild": null,
    "metrics": null,
    "name": "PIPELINE_NAME",
    "path": "\\",
    "project": {
      "abbreviation": null,
      "defaultTeamImageUrl": null,
      "description": null,
      "id": "99a1b81a-ca3b-418a-86cf-0965eaba6dab",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2019-12-13T20:54:20.28Z",
      "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
      "revision": 462,
      "state": "wellFormed",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION_NAME/_apis/projects/99a1b81a-ca3b-418a-86cf-0965eaba6dab",
      "visibility": "private"
    },
    "quality": "definition",
    "queue": {
      "id": 501,
      "name": "Azure Pipelines",
      "pool": {
        "id": 65,
        "isHosted": true,
        "name": "Azure Pipelines"
      },
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION_NAME/_apis/build/Queues/501"
    },
    "queueStatus": "enabled",
    "revision": 30,
    "type": "build",
    "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Definition/541",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION_NAME/99a1b81a-ca3b-418a-86cf-0965eaba6dab/_apis/build/Definitions/541?revision=30"
  }
]
PS C:\>
```

However, if I try to assign the results to a variable, the shell/script hangs instead:

```bsh
PS C:\> $pipelines = az pipelines list --project PROJECT_NAME --name PIPELINE_NAME --output json
This command is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
```

And the cursor jumps to the character 61 position and just stays there forever.

What may be the cause of this behaviour?  I feel like the preview warning is causing some trouble, but I was not sure how to suppress it.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. above command worked for me.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue with az pipelines show instead of list. I can also reproduce the cursor jumping around. My azure-devops extension is on version 0.17.0.

Comment: After a wasted morning ... this question would be more discoverable if the title was renamed to mention more relevant keywords like: output text invisible

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is going to sound odd, but this is a rendering issue only - the app hasn't hung at all, it just stopped the console from outputting correctly, including the prompt after the command finishes.

At the top of your script add the following:

```
$PSBackgroundColor = $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor
$PSForegroundColor = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor

function Reset-Console {
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $PSBackgroundColor
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $PSForegroundColor
}
```

Then after running the command:

```
Reset-Console
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: A shorter similar thing: [Console]::ResetColor()

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the previous answer this is due to the color output of the azure cli (In this case the warning text) messes up the terminal.

Since PR [[Core] Knack adoption #12604](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/12604) it is possible to disable coloring of output for Azure cli by setting the environment variable `AZURE_CORE_NO_COLOR` to `True` (o alternatively by setting the `[core] no_color=True` option in `~/.azure/config`

I am using i successfully with version 2.14.2 of Azure CLI.

From the description of PR [[Core] Knack adoption #12604](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/12604)

> [Core] PREVIEW: Allow disabling color by setting AZURE_CORE_NO_COLOR
> environment variable to True or [core] no_color=True config (#12601)